# generalizing expressions under binders

Tags: coq, coq-tactic, ltac

I need to generalize expression under the binder. For example, I have in my goal two expressions:

```
(fun a b => g a b c)
```

and

```
(fun a b => f (g a b c))
```

And I want to generalize `g _ _ c` part:

One way to do is to rewrite them first into:

```
(fun a b => (fun x y =>  g x y c) a b)
```

and the second into:

```
(fun a b =>
   f (
       (fun x y =>  g x y c) a b
   ))
```

And then, to generalize `(fun x y,  g x y c)` as `somefun` with type `A -> A -> A`. This will turn my expressions into:

```
(fun a b => somefun a b)
```

and

```
(fun a b => f (somefun a b))
```

The difficulty here is that the expression I am trying to generalize is under the binder. I could not find either a tactic or LTAC expression to manipulate it. How can I do something like this?

Comment: https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Logic.FunctionalExtensionality.html ?

Comment: (1) Is there a [mcve]? (2) What does `(fun a b, g a b c)` mean?

Comment: Sorry about notation error. `(fun a b, ...)` is actually `(fun a b => ...)`. I have fixed the example. I can try to make a complete example, but the point is not proving a particular one but rather figuring out a technique to do something like this.

Comment: You can create a complete example, without being too specific. Just quantify over your functions and write a silly lemma about them. Here, this is just too vague.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two keys to this answer: the [`change` tactic](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/V8.6.1/refman/Reference-Manual010.html#hevea_tactic130), which replaces one term with a convertible one, and generalizing `c` so that you deal not with `g _ _ c` but `fun z => g _ _ z`; this second key allows you to deal with `g` rather than with `g` applied to its arguments.  Here, I use the `pose` tactic to control what function applications get β reduced:

```
Axiom A : Type.
Axiom f : A -> A.
Axiom g : A -> A -> A -> A.
Goal forall c, (fun a b => g a b c) = (fun a b => f (g a b c)).
Proof.
  intro c.
  pose (fun z x y => g x y z) as g'.
  change g with (fun x y z => g' z x y).
  (*   (fun a b : A => (fun x y z : A => g' z x y) a b c) =
       (fun a b : A => f ((fun x y z : A => g' z x y) a b c)) *)
  cbv beta.
  (* (fun a b : A => g' c a b) = (fun a b : A => f (g' c a b)) *)
  generalize (g' c); intro somefun; clear g'.
  (* (fun a b : A => somefun a b) = (fun a b : A => f (somefun a b)) *)
```

Here is an alternate version that uses `id` (the identity function) to block `cbv beta`, rather than using `pose`:

```
Axiom A : Type.
Axiom f : A -> A.
Axiom g : A -> A -> A -> A.
Goal forall c, (fun a b => g a b c) = (fun a b => f (g a b c)).
Proof.
  intro c.
  change g with (fun a' b' c' => (fun z => id (fun x y => g x y z)) c' a' b').
  (*   (fun a b : A =>
        (fun a' b' c' : A => (fun z : A => id (fun x y : A => g x y z)) c' a' b') a b c) =
       (fun a b : A =>
        f
          ((fun a' b' c' : A => (fun z : A => id (fun x y : A => g x y z)) c' a' b') a
             b c)) *)
  cbv beta.
  (* (fun a b : A => id (fun x y : A => g x y c) a b) =
     (fun a b : A => f (id (fun x y : A => g x y c) a b)) *)
  generalize (id (fun x y : A => g x y c)); intro somefun.
  (* (fun a b : A => somefun a b) = (fun a b : A => f (somefun a b)) *)
```